# How to convert python dict to raw url-encoded form data?

Tags: python, web, python-requests, urlencode, form-data

In Chrome network tab, I can find requests. I want to replicate one request in python.

Here is the URL-encoded version, and it works when I pass it to `requests.post`

```py
res = requests.post("https://www.cmskchp.com/sailingsJson", headers=headers, data=formdata)
```

[image]

Chrome also provides a parsed version of Form data
[image]

I tried to pass a python dict to `requests.post` but always get internal server error.

I have tried both `data` and `json` parameters or `requests.post`.

Also tried encoding using `json.dumps`, `urllib.parse.urlencode`, `urllib.parse.quote_plus`, none of them worked for me.

Can someone show me the correct way to encode python dict into raw form data?

When I right click the request and copy the javascript fetch code of the request the form data is already encoded. How does Chrome encode/decode it?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual data!

Answer (score 1):

Your challenge is the encoding of the Chinese characters in python.

Doing some research around it, it seems that behind the scenes there is some fun going on with `unicode` and `ascii`.

You can see this - Try this as a debug line:

```
rawjson = {'toDate2': '08月26日', 'toWeek': 'END'}
encodedjson = urllib.parse.quote(json.dumps(rawjson))
print (encodedjson)
```

output is:

```
%7B%22toDate2%22%3A%20%2208%5Cu670826%5Cu65e5%22%2C%20%22toWeek%22%3A%20%22END%22%7D
```

Stick that in a [URLdecoder](https://www.urldecoder.org/) = and you get:

```
{"toDate2": "08\u670826\u65e5", "toWeek": "END"}
```

The chinese characters have gone. You've now got `\u6708` and `\u65e5`. It's not the expected format on the server so no wonder the server gives you a `500`.

You need to tell python to make it `UTF-8`, and you need to ensure the `content-type` is set in the headers.

- headers: `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`
- a UTF-8 string: `json.dumps(payload, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')`

This is a working script which returns a `200`:

```py
import requests
import urllib.parse
import json

#for copying simplicity from chrome devtools
null = None
false = False

#the json
payload = {
    "userType":"LTP001","startSite":"SK","endSite":"HKM","toDate":"2021-08-26","toDate2":"08月26日","toWeek":"周四","backDate":"","backDate2":"","backWeek":"","endSiteName":"Hong+Kong,+Hong+KongMacau","startSiteName":"Shekou,+shenzhen","sailingType":"0","lineId":"SK-HKM","airportTime":null,"lineType":null,"toTime":null,"flightCode":null,"flightName":null,"flightNo":null,"flightId":null,"flightDate":null,"flightHours":null,"flightMinute":null,"chanId":"1","isSeckill":false,"isSeckills":false,"nightFlight":0,"batchNo":null,"hsyLineId":null,"memberId":null,
}

payload = urllib.parse.quote(json.dumps(payload, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8'))
payload = payload.replace('%20','')
payload = 'siteResJson=' + payload

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
}
Res_post = requests.post("https://www.cmskchp.com/sailingsJson", data=payload, headers=headers)
```

This is the response:
[image]